# Are there any subtle differences between SeriesCollection.Add() and SeriesCollection.NewSeries()?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using vb.net to control an excel workbook.

I have noticed there are two options for creating a series in the series collection of a chart, either using `SeriesCollection.Add()` with some starting parameters specified as arguments, or using `SeriesCollection.NewSeries()` without initializing parameters.

I was wondering, besides the obvious difference that they are intialized differently, are there are any difference between the two that I should be aware of?

I am wondering because I have used `SeriesCollection.Add()` in the past, but now want to specify the x and y values more specifically than that method allows.  This lead me to finding the `SeriesCollection.NewSeries()` method, however I am unsure if there are any important differences that are not obvious.

My purpose is to create a new series, and to assign the series to a variable of type `excel.series` for future manipulation.  I really do not want to specify anything on start, but am not aware if this could cause other problems.  thanks in advance!

Comment: `NewSeries` returns the added series object, whereas `Add` does not (XL2007 help: "This method does not actually return a Series object as stated in the Object Browser").  This makes `Add` less convenient if you want to set more advanced options on the series.

Comment: so if anything, using `newseries` should be beneficial? what is actually returned by `add` then???

Comment: After testing, it seems the Help is wrong and it does in fact return a series.  Given that, the two methods seem pretty similar...

Comment: Sounds like you understand my confusion now :/

Answer (score 2):

The NewSeries command returns the new series.  Even though Add states that it returns a series that it adds to the collection it does not.  The documentation may be what is causing your confusion here.  Check out this MSDN article on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194065.aspx

Comment: you are correct, the documentation is confusing: it isn't right or consistent. The MSDN page there is not correct as to what actually occurs in practice, which is that `add` **does** return a series object.